# Launch Ubuntu Budgie Desktop Settings from Command Line-Cannot Open Start Menu

Tags: command-line, settings, panel, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I installed Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 recently and made the mistake of removing the start/search menu icon from the panel.  Now I cannot open the start/search menu at all and so cannot open Budgie desktop settings to revert it.  How do I open Budgie desktop settings from the terminal, or what configuration file do I edit to add the search icon (and what do I add to the file)?

Answer (score 3):

Press  CTRL+ALT+T to open a terminal

Then type:

```
nohup budgie-panel --reset --replace &
```

This will reset your panel back to its defaults.